# Resources on conformal mapping and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I am currently working on a project which utilizes the method of conformal mapping to model microstrip lines. I am using this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1125810) as a resource. I am new to complex analysis and require an introductory text resource to get me started.

Does anyone know of a paper, textbook, or other document that I could use as a reliable reference to learn about complex analysis and eventually conformal mapping?

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Princeton-Lectures-No/dp/0691113858](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113858)

Elias Stein and Rami Shakarchi's Complex Analysis book.